# How to enable ctrl + A (check all option ) in a table (inside jsp page ) that has a list of checkbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How to enable ctrl + A (check all option ) in a table (inside jsp page ) that has a list of checkboxes using jQuery ?

Thanks
Matt

Comment: The Ctrl+A key combination has a different meaning and purpose in a web browser. It is intended to select all the text on the webpage, not to check some checkboxes.

Comment: Ok , so do you have any idea what short cut should i be using for a check all option , i am totally newbie for jsps,jquerry and all web based stuff.

Comment: You could provide some UI element such as a button or another checkbox which when clicked will check/uncheck all other checkboxes.

Comment: I think you should use a button or another ui element instead or in addition to the keyboard shortcut. Most people don't even know you can use shortcuts in the browser, they need a visual cue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This provides a poc for the functionality you may use as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/HVxss/1/

```
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<div id="test">Select All</div>

$("#test").click(function(){
  $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Comment: Sorry we already have a button for checkall , but need to enable short cut key  that is what i am wondering . thanks for the quick response all.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a checkbox that says something like "Select all", then use the following jQuery to check all checkboxes when the user checks it.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('input.checkall).change(function() { 
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) { 
            $(this).closest('ul').siblings('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/
using javascript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
window.addEvent( 'keydown', function( evt ){ 
   if( evt.key == 'enter' && evt.shift ) 
      //code to chck all option
}); 
</script>
```